# Get folder name from full folder path

Tags: c#, directory

How do I get the folder name from the full path of the application?

This is the file path below,

```
c:\projects\root\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text
```

Here "text" is the folder name.

How can I get that folder name from this path?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

See [DirectoryInfo.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx):

```
string dirName = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text").Name;
```

Comment: Doesn't this require that the folder actually exists in the file system (the folder name would *still* be "text" for that full file path if folder "c:\projects\root\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text" does not (currently) exist in the file system)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, no.  I just tested this and the method returns the name of the lowest level folder from the string, even if the folder path does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. But I'm a little puzzled that System.IO.Directory does not support such an operation.

Comment: @anhoppe - I agree. Another option I saw is Path.GetDirectoryName https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx -- but will not be able to test it out until tomorrow.

Answer (score 31):

I think you want to get parent folder name from file path. It is easy to get. 
One way is to create a `FileInfo` type object and use its `Directory` property.

Example:

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo("c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text\abc.txt");

String dirName = fInfo.Directory.Name;
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
var myFolderName = @"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text";
var result = Path.GetFileName(myFolderName);
```

Comment: if you have a filename into string, it returns filename too

Comment: In this case, text is the (extension-less) file name. I thought that was what the OP was after. If it's a folder or a file name does not actually matter. If the string does not contain the file name, this code will give him what he is after.

Comment: Unless the paths ends with a \ like this: `@"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text\"`

Comment: this doesn't work for a folder. I get a blank string. There must be a file present

Comment: This works just fine if the folder path does not contain a trailing backslash (like for instance a folder path returned from [Path.GetDirectoryName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)). The name of that function, GetFileName(), is a bit misleading, though.

Comment: Is this better, in performance, than DirectoryInfo and FileInfo since a new object is not being initialized?

Answer (score 10):

You could use this:

```
string path = @"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text";
string lastDirectory = path.Split(new char[] { System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
```

Comment: what if the path looks like this: @"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text\", so with an extra DirectorySeparatorChar

Comment: @Alex - I modified my code to make it work with those kind of paths as well. `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` does the trick.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx, FileInfo can throw an exception if the required permission is not given.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `Path.GetFileName`

Here - Extract folder name from the full path of a folder:

```
string folderName = Path.GetFileName(@"c:\projects\root\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text");//Return "text"
```

Here is some extra - Extract folder name from the full path of a file:

```
string folderName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\projects\root\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text\GTA.exe"));//Return "text"
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured there's no way except going into the file system to find out if text.txt is a directory or just a file. If you wanted something simple, maybe you can just use:

```
s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"\"));
```

Comment: To avoid a slash at the front of the string:
s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);

Answer (score 2):

In this case the file which you want to get is stored in the strpath variable:

```
string strPath = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + "/contents/member/" + strFileName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative method that worked for me without having to create a DirectoryInfo object. The key point is that `GetFileName()` works when there is no trailing slash in the path.

```
var name = Path.GetFileName(path.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
```

Example:

```
var list = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*")
        .Select(p => new
        {
            id = "id_" + p.GetHashCode().ToString("x"),
            text = Path.GetFileName(p.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)),
            icon = "fa fa-folder",
            children = true
        })
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(p => p.text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done like so;

```
var directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text");
```

Comment: this will return an empty string

Comment: @disklosr - just tested with ScriptCs and it returns 'text'

Comment: This works just fine if the folder path does not contain a trailing backslash (like for instance a folder path returned from [Path.GetDirectoryName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)). The name of that function, GetFileName(), is a bit misleading, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229309/2060966) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18131681/2060966) (but fixed)

```
using static System.IO.Path;

var dir = GetFileName(path?.TrimEnd(DirectorySeparatorChar, AltDirectorySeparatorChar));
```

Explanation of `GetFileName` from [.NET source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,95facc58d06cadd0):

> Returns the name and extension parts of the given path. The resulting
>   string contains the characters of path that follow the last
>   backslash ("\"), slash ("/"), or colon (":") character in 
>   path. The resulting string is the entire path if path 
>   contains no backslash after removing trailing slashes, slash, or colon characters. The resulting 
>   string is null if path is null.