# How do I store only the folder names as an array and not the while path (C#)

Tags: c#

So I know how to store the full path but not just the end folder names, for example I've already got an array but is there any method to remove certain characters from all arrays or just get folder names from a path?

Edit: string[] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
      That's what I use to get all folder names but that gets me the whole path
Edit:They need to be stored in an Array

Edit: sorry , I need an array with values such as "mpbeach","blabla","keyboard" and not E:\Zmod\idk\DLC List Generator\DLC List Generator by Frazzlee\ , so basically not the full path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get folder name from full file path - C#, ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229292/get-folder-name-from-full-file-path-c-asp-net)

Comment: What do you mean by "end folder names?" Path has GetFileName and if you split the whole URL by backslash, the next-to-last item in Length would be the "last folder"

Comment: I'm finding your question very confusing. Could you please provide some expected output with mock values? I've read your post multiple times and I'm still not certain what you're asking for is a duplicate or if everybody is just as confused as me.

Comment: Still think my answer is the way to get what you need - despite that it's getting downvoted. I don't think people are understanding what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for string operations... Just use [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
var allFolders = new DirectoryInfo(directory).GetDirectories()
                .Select(x => x.Name)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: That gives a list of folders in a given directory,no? OP is asking how to extract the last folder name from a file URL.

Comment: `That gives a list of folders in a given directory,no?` **YES**

Comment: I don't understnad the x => part sorry

Comment: I know it changes item to array but do I keep it the same?

Comment: @FranzLophanor It is called lamda expressions (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) , it is a delagate that takes a *DirectoryInfo* class and returns its name... BTW: All you need to use it is including *using System.Linq*

Comment: @FranzLophanor `keep it the same` If you mean "keep the same order" then yes.... You can also add `.OrderBy(x=>x)` to sort it...

Comment: It tells me "the type or namespace linq does not exist"

Comment: Ok I had target framework for 2.0, changed it to 4.0 and works fine now, thanks very much

Comment: @FranzLophanor If one of answers worked for you, don't forget to *accept* it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done, sorry I was on a timer for 15 minutes, (I'm a new user)

Answer (score 4):

This works.

```
string[] allFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory)
            .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).ToArray();
```

This also works. Difference is we are using `List<string>` instead of `string[]`

```
List<string> allFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory)
                          .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).ToList();
```

#### Example 1: Uses `string[] allFolders`

#### Test Folder

[image]

#### In VS IDE, in Debug Mode

[image]

#### Example 2: Uses `List<string> allFolders`

#### Test Folder

[image]

#### In VS IDE, in Debug Mode

[image]

#### Example 2: Uses `string[] allFolders`

Answer (score -6):

**NOTE** I'm taking your question to mean how to extract the last folder name from a file URL. Others are reading this as how to extract the names of folders in a directory. If I'm wrong, it's because I'm misinterpreting your question.

Split by backslash to get folders. The next-to-last value is the last folder:

```
string folder = @"c:\mydrive\testfolder\hello.txt";
string[] parts = folder.Split('\\');
string lastFolder = parts[parts.Length - 1];
//Yields "testfolder";
```

Moving that forward to what you want:

```
 private string[] foldersOnly(){
  List<string> folders = new List<string>();
  string[] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
  foreach(string folder in allfolders){
       string[] parts = folder.Split('\\');
       folders.Add(parts[parts.Length-1]);
  }
  }
  return folders.ToArray();
```

Comment: This solution is prone to errors. What would happen if the folder passed in is C:\mydrive\testfolder\

Comment: Then you get "testfolder," which is the last folder in the URL.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Actually you'd get the empty string because `string.Split` will leave the empty entry in there.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when I get home