# C# - Get subfolder name that contain specific character of file

Tags: c#, linq, directory, console-application

I want to know which folder contains files which have a `$` in their names.
But I will get duplicate folder names if I use this code:

```
string local = @"C:\test\";
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(local, "*$*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(string dir in dirs)
{
   string a = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir));
}
```

This is the content of the test folder:

> - C:\test\20170321\$123.txt
> - C:\test\20170321\2$4.txt
> - C:\test\20170322\567.txt
> - C:\test\20170322\abc.txt

[image]

should be get result only 1 20170321

Comment: then only select the directory names, and unique them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string local = @"C:\test\";
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(local, "*$*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
List<string> singleDirNames = dirs.Select(x=> Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Explanation: Select from all filenames the directory and take only the distinct values of it into a list

**EDIT:**

As I just realized, you don't want the entire path, so to get the result from your post you need to use the `Path.GetFileName()` (there should be another way, I am looking for it):

```
List<string> singleDirNames = dirs
                           .Select(x=> Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(x)))
                           .Distinct().ToList();
```

Found it. Here would be actually the direct way to access the containing folder inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229311/5174469):

```
List<string> singleDirNames = dirs.Select(x=> new FileInfo(x).Directory.Name)
                                  .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: @Y.C You're welcome. I found the direct way of accessing the folder. Have a look at the edit. I don't know whether it is better, but it does not try to access a file name and gets the folder. It accesses the folder directly