# how to get file path using browse button in vb6

Tags: vb6, filepath, common-dialog

I am using this code, it gives the file name like "C:\File\sample.txt". But I am in need of getting path like "C:\File\". How can I get this path?

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
    CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
    txtPath1.Text = CommonDialog1.FileName 
End Sub
```

Comment: instead of FileName have you tried FilePath ?

Comment: I tried but it there no such command in CommonDialog.It shows Compile error like "Method or datamember not found"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
txtPath1.Text = Mid(CommonDialog1.FileName, 1, InStrRev(CommonDialog1.FileName, "\"))
```

Comment: I'm new to vb6. So I don't know why it shows the error **'Invalid Qualifier'** for your code. It shows error in  '**path**.LastIndexOf("\")'

Comment: @SachaKarthi I updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In FileName is Your dialog Box FileName that Contains Your File Name..You Need to Remove It By Finding Filename with a `\`

```
   With CommonDialog1
    TextBox1.Text = .FileName.Substring(0, .FileName.LastIndexOf("\"))
   End With
```

This code Finds Last `\` from your File Path ("C:\File\sample.txt").Basically File Path Has Filename at the end of File Path.So Find the Last `\` and Remove it. this Is working Fine form me.

Comment: This answer concerns VB.NET. If the OP was using VB.NET (which they do not appear to), then this answer [would be wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5229292/11683).