# .Net hook to get folder name from path in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I saw this solution:
[Get folder name from full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229292/get-folder-name-from-full-file-path)

And the accepted answer was:

```
string dirName = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\projects\roott\wsdlproj\devlop\beta2\text").Name;
```

But this is in C#. I'm currently trying to .net hook that method and get it working in powershell, but I'm unsure of how to use the object properly.

This is what I have currently:

```
$AppPath = "$null"
$PathArray = @()
$ParentFolderNames = @()
$DirObject = New-Object -TypeName System.IO


Get-ChildItem -Path $ServerPath | Select-Object FullName | ForEach-Object {

    ## $_.GetType()
    $String = ("$_.").ToString()
    $PathArray += $String.Split("=")[1]

}

foreach ($object in $PathArray){
    ## $ParentFolderNames += $object.Split("$\*")[1]

    $ParentFolderNames += $DirObject.DirectoryInfo("$Object").Name

}
$ParentFolderNames
```

The error I'm getting is "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." However, $object is not null.

I get the desired output when I call it in the foreach loop. But I can't get that .net hook to grab the last folder name.

Edit: So I realized I was trying to invent the wheel. I should have just done "Select-Object Name" instead of "FullName". And then used Trim to get rid of any characters I didn't want.

But I'd still like to know how I could use that .Net hook properly

Comment: In powershell, you can just typecast a string: `([IO.DirectoryInfo]'C:\path').Name`

Comment: You can also use `Split-Path`: `Split-Path -Path 'C:\Temp\Data' -Leaf`, which returns `Data`

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions worked for me.